# MySQL PDO query syntax error with ? parameters

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, parameters, pdo

as a newbie, I've followed PHP MySQL tutorials advising the use of regular MySQL php functions. However, since I've been told that PDO is the better alternative, I've been converting my code to that. I just ran into the following problem:

```
    $query = $uspdb->prepare("SELECT post_id, is_approved, reports FROM ? WHERE id=? AND ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $table, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(2, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(3, checkPermission("comment_moderation"),PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
    $query->execute;
    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The first line throws the following PDO exception:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? WHERE id=? AND ?' at line 1
```

Why is that? I have no idea what could be wrong with the syntax. The [tutorial I'm reading](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) tells me that I should be using bindValue or execute(array(stuff)) to add parameters rather than ".$id." and the likes, since it's safer, but this isn't working for whatever reason.

Comment: You bind the table name as `PDO::PARAM_INT`, quite sure that's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, prepared statement can represent a data literal only. (in case of emulated prepares).
So, a developer have to take care of identifiers oneself - PDO offers **no help** for this matter.

To make a dynamical identifier safe, one have to follow 2 strict rules:

1. To format identifier properly. Means

   - enclose identifier in backticks.
   - escape backticks inside by doubling them.
2. To verify it against a **hardcoded whitelist**.

After the formatting, it is safe to insert the $table variable into query. So, the code would be:

```
$field = "`".str_replace("`","``",$field)."`";
$sql   = "SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY $field";
```

However, although such a formatting would be enough for the cases like ORDER BY, for the most other cases there is a possibility for a different sort of injection: letting a user to choose a table or a field they can see, we may reveal some sensitive information, like password or other personal data. So, it's always better to check dynamical identifiers against a list of allowed values. Here is a brief example:

```
$allowed = array("name","price","qty");
$key = array_search($_GET['field'], $allowed));
if ($key === false) {
    throw new Exception('Wrong field name');
}
$field = $allowed[$key];
$query   = "SELECT $field FROM t"; //value is safe
```

Comment: Do I still have to sanitize and whitelist input like this if it is not actually left to the user? Can attackers potentially insert whatever they want into such a variable, or only if I allow the user to modify it?

The $table variable in my code is handled like this (the $type variable being a $_GET:
    switch($type) {
        case "review":
            $table = "site_cmt_reviews";
            $posttable = "site_review";
            break;
        default:
            $table = "site_cmt_articles";
            $posttable = "site_article";
    }

Comment: it doesn't matter. User input has nothing to do here. It's rules of creating SQL queries. Have always to be followed. Or, sooner or later, it will be injected.

Comment: Your switch is actually the very white list I am talking about. Just a longer code.

Comment: Formatting is still required though.

Comment: Can this formatting be replaced by a simple call of mysql_real_escape_string($table)?

Answer (score 0):

As is typical, I solve my problem seconds after posing the question.

The problem is that you can only bind key values like this, not table or column names. I'll have to keep inserting the table and column names manually just as before:

```
$query = $uspdb->prepare("SELECT post_id, is_approved, reports FROM $table WHERE id=? AND ?");
$query->execute(array($id,checkPermission("comment_moderation")));
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

If the table or column name is left to the user's discretion, you should go through additional steps to sanitize it, which are detailed in Your Common Sense's response above. In my case it was the following code:

```
$type = $_GET[type];

switch($type) {
    case "review":
        $table = "site_cmt_reviews";
        break;
    default:
        $table = "site_cmt_articles";
}
```

Still, thanks for reading!

Comment: And so have an injection.

Comment: Since, in my example, the $table variable is determined by code and cannot be changed/maliciously exploited by a user, that doesn't really run the risk of an injection, I think? Though I guess it should still be recommended to sanitize the input if it is.

Comment: Nobody knows what is determined in your code and how it can be changed in the future. Neither your question nor this answer ever mention it.

Comment: Edited the response to make that clearer and to refer to your post.

Comment: This one is a way to go.